# javascript views support for asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Is there any plugin or library that enables javascript views in asp.net mvc 3 such as the ones in rails where you put your javascript code in a view and then return it from the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    var model = ...
    Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";
    return View(model);
}
```

and in `Foo.cshtml`:

```
@model AppName.Models.SomeModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
var someProperty = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.SomeProperty));
alert(someProperty);
```